# Unable to see Jasper Report Sub Report table data populated with JSON

Tags: json, jasper-reports, subreport

I've created a Jasper Report that only consists of a summary band with a table element.  The data source is JSON and I am able to preview this report perfectly fine. (subJSONTest.jrxml)  When I now try and use this report as a sub report in another jrxml file (JSONTest.jrxml), I cannot see any data at all when I attempt to preview the main report.  Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

I expected the same table data to be displayed from main ==> sub report, just as I did when previewing the sub report on it's own.

subJSONTest.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 8.1.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.20.0-2bc7ab61c56f459e8176eb05c7705e145cd400ad  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="JSONTest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="eeca104d-f460-4de0-8229-80d057e025a0">
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="f2dcbb4a-78c8-45b9-8086-0ab0924618fd">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="jsonTEST"/>
        <queryString language="jsonql">
            <![CDATA[report.samples_by_result_cfu]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="suite" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="suite"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[suite]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="qtr" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="qtr"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[qtr]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="mth" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="mth"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[mth]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="product" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="product"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[product]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="analysis" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="analysis"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[analysis]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="component" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="component"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[component]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="sample_number" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="sample_number"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[sample_number]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <group name="suite">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{suite}]]></groupExpression>
        </group>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[report]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <summary>
        <band height="213">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="-10" y="6" width="550" height="200" uuid="eceddb4d-fca7-475f-b050-c22c25f5fcbf">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.autoresize.next" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="ad76e183-2756-412b-a5c8-1d392d454155">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("samples_by_result_cfu")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="80" uuid="3a9a2cfb-62f3-44cf-9901-89d492f6296d">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="245b781a-20a8-490b-b806-a6aa479f5844"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Suite]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="cd4a9ec3-1c43-4517-a1cb-e110acddc058"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{suite}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="66" uuid="2ebad35a-8d61-482e-b0da-fdd29e41f3e6">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="2a96df8d-a7f4-42de-85b3-cd67732769e1"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Quarter]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="4eb3e9b7-68c4-4349-bcbb-a72b6799e4fe"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{qtr}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="66" uuid="019748dc-e41f-490d-8fdd-84f5dfd35f11">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="8328412e-24eb-48b3-9513-1a7309143aea"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Product]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="e74b5e30-03d5-4974-acd0-3521b5b4be6e"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{product}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="98" uuid="665a0eb1-2455-4be8-a9f6-8ba49603f7e8">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="98" height="30" uuid="cfbea91e-839a-4a03-bdd6-4d9f535dfb95"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Analysis]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="98" height="30" uuid="8d1f34e1-3259-4574-8398-cef0ae985c47"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{analysis}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="a91fc2ca-2fc2-4547-9680-785e6ff9b541">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="36f35980-4b3b-4656-97b3-907a579fee47"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Component]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="234d2df6-0f99-48b5-84e3-f80225928ad7"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{component}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="80" uuid="d661ab9f-9da5-40ea-b49f-67044cdb5b47">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="b09d22ab-09ed-46b7-be85-a36ea6cd1fcb"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Sample Number]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="5ab7ca26-4cac-449b-983e-c257c8335229"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sample_number}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

JSONTest.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 8.1.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.20.0-2bc7ab61c56f459e8176eb05c7705e145cd400ad  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="JSONTest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="eeca104d-f460-4de0-8229-80d057e025a0">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="jsonTEST"/>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[report]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="248" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="-10" y="10" width="570" height="200" uuid="08b3b95b-e7c1-477d-8579-de67c5348404"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("samples_by_result_cfu")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subJSONTest.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

JSON Test Data

```
{
  "report": {
    "filter_parameters": {
      "suite": [
        "CELPHX-AA",
        "CELPHX-BB"
      ],
      "product": [
        "ROOM"
      ],
      "show_er": true,
      "end_date": "2022-02-02",
      "show_crr": true,
      "show_oos": false,
      "show_oot": false,
      "component": [],
      "test_name": [],
      "instrument": [],
      "start_date": "2022-01-31",
      "product_lot": [],
      "quarter_end": "2",
      "report_type": "Trending",
      "process_unit": [],
      "quarter_start": "1",
      "sample_status": [],
      "show_raw_data": true,
      "media_standard": [],
      "sampling_point": [],
      "date_range_type": "quarter",
      "quarter_end_year": 2022,
      "quarter_start_year": 2022
    },
    "samples_by_result_cfu": [
      {
        "suite": "CELPHX-AA",
        "qtr": "2 2022",
        "mth": "APR 2022",
        "sampled_date": "2022-04-12",
        "product": "ROOM",
        "analysis": "MICROBIAL_CT_EM_PHX",
        "component": "Total Count - Bacteria/Yeast/Mold",
        "product_spec": "Action >=1; TNTC (OOS)",
        "sample_number": 792328,
        "status": "A",
        "result": 0,
        "units": "CFU",
        "in_control": "T",
        "in_spec": "T",
        "number_of_samples": 0,
        "number_of_oot": 0,
        "number_of_oos": 0,
        "number_of_tntc": 0
      },
      {
        "suite": "CELPHX-AA",
        "qtr": "2 2022",
        "mth": "APR 2022",
        "sampled_date": "2022-04-12",
        "product": "ROOM",
        "analysis": "MICROBIAL_CT_EM_PHX",
        "component": "Total Count - Bacteria/Yeast/Mold",
        "product_spec": "Action >=1; TNTC (OOS)",
        "sample_number": 792329,
        "status": "A",
        "result": 0,
        "units": "CFU",
        "in_control": "T",
        "in_spec": "T",
        "number_of_samples": 0,
        "number_of_oot": 0,
        "number_of_oos": 0,
        "number_of_tntc": 0
      },
      {
        "suite": "CELPHX-AA",
        "qtr": "2 2022",
        "mth": "APR 2022",
        "sampled_date": "2022-04-12",
        "product": "ROOM",
        "analysis": "MICROBIAL_CT_EM_PHX",
        "component": "Total Count - Bacteria/Yeast/Mold",
        "product_spec": "Action >=1; TNTC (OOS)",
        "sample_number": 792330,
        "status": "A",
        "result": 0,
        "units": "CFU",
        "in_control": "T",
        "in_spec": "T",
        "number_of_samples": 0,
        "number_of_oot": 0,
        "number_of_oos": 0,
        "number_of_tntc": 0
      },
      {
        "suite": "CELPHX-AA",
        "qtr": "2 2022",
        "mth": "APR 2022",
        "sampled_date": "2022-04-12",
        "product": "ROOM",
        "analysis": "MICROBIAL_CT_EM_PHX",
        "component": "Total Count - Bacteria/Yeast/Mold",
        "product_spec": "Action >=1; TNTC (OOS)",
        "sample_number": 792418,
        "status": "A",
        "result": 0,
        "units": "CFU",
        "in_control": "T",
        "in_spec": "T",
        "number_of_samples": 0,
        "number_of_oot": 0,
        "number_of_oos": 0,
        "number_of_tntc": 0
      },
      {
        "suite": "CELPHX-AA",
        "qtr": "2 2022",
        "mth": "APR 2022",
        "sampled_date": "2022-04-12",
        "product": "ROOM",
        "analysis": "MICROBIAL_CT_EM_PHX",
        "component": "Total Count - Bacteria/Yeast/Mold",
        "product_spec": "Action >=1; TNTC (OOS)",
        "sample_number": 792431,
        "status": "A",
        "result": 0,
        "units": "CFU",
        "in_control": "T",
        "in_spec": "T",
        "number_of_samples": 0,
        "number_of_oot": 0,
        "number_of_oos": 0,
        "number_of_tntc": 0
      },
      {
        "suite": "CELPHX-AA",
        "qtr": "2 2022",
        "mth": "APR 2022",
        "sampled_date": "2022-04-12",
        "product": "ROOM",
        "analysis": "MICROBIAL_CT_EM_PHX",
        "component": "Total Count - Bacteria/Yeast/Mold",
        "product_spec": "Action >=1; TNTC (OOS)",
        "sample_number": 792432,
        "status": "A",
        "result": 5,
        "units": "CFU",
        "in_control": "T",
        "in_spec": "F",
        "number_of_samples": 10,
        "number_of_oot": 0,
        "number_of_oos": 0,
        "number_of_tntc": 0
      },
      {
        "suite": "CELPHX-AA",
        "qtr": "2 2022",
        "mth": "APR 2022",
        "sampled_date": "2022-04-12",
        "product": "ROOM",
        "analysis": "MICROBIAL_CT_EM_PHX",
        "component": "Total Count - Bacteria/Yeast/Mold",
        "product_spec": "Action >=1; TNTC (OOS)",
        "sample_number": 792433,
        "status": "A",
        "result": 0,
        "units": "CFU",
        "in_control": "T",
        "in_spec": "T",
        "number_of_samples": 0,
        "number_of_oot": 0,
        "number_of_oos": 0,
        "number_of_tntc": 0
      },
      {
        "suite": "CELPHX-AA",
        "qtr": "2 2022",
        "mth": "APR 2022",
        "sampled_date": "2022-04-12",
        "product": "ROOM",
        "analysis": "MICROBIAL_CT_EM_PHX",
        "component": "Total Count - Bacteria/Yeast/Mold",
        "product_spec": "Alert >=3; Action >=5; TNTC (OOS)",
        "sample_number": 792201,
        "status": "A",
        "result": 0,
        "units": "CFU",
        "in_control": "T",
        "in_spec": "T",
        "number_of_samples": 0,
        "number_of_oot": 0,
        "number_of_oos": 0,
        "number_of_tntc": 0
      },
      {
        "suite": "CELPHX-AA",
        "qtr": "2 2022",
        "mth": "APR 2022",
        "sampled_date": "2022-04-12",
        "product": "ROOM",
        "analysis": "MICROBIAL_CT_EM_PHX",
        "component": "Total Count - Bacteria/Yeast/Mold",
        "product_spec": "Alert >=3; Action >=5; TNTC (OOS)",
        "sample_number": 792210,
        "status": "A",
        "result": 0,
        "units": "CFU",
        "in_control": "T",
        "in_spec": "T",
        "number_of_samples": 0,
        "number_of_oot": 0,
        "number_of_oos": 0,
        "number_of_tntc": 0
      },
      {
        "suite": "CELPHX-AA",
        "qtr": "2 2022",
        "mth": "APR 2022",
        "sampled_date": "2022-04-12",
        "product": "ROOM",
        "analysis": "MICROBIAL_CT_EM_PHX",
        "component": "Total Count - Bacteria/Yeast/Mold",
        "product_spec": "Alert >=3; Action >=5; TNTC (OOS)",
        "sample_number": 792211,
        "status": "A",
        "result": 0,
        "units": "CFU",
        "in_control": "T",
        "in_spec": "T",
        "number_of_samples": 0,
        "number_of_oot": 0,
        "number_of_oos": 0,
        "number_of_tntc": 0
      },
      {
        "suite": "CELPHX-AA",
        "qtr": "2 2022",
        "mth": "APR 2022",
        "sampled_date": "2022-04-12",
        "product": "ROOM",
        "analysis": "MICROBIAL_CT_EM_PHX",
        "component": "Total Count - Bacteria/Yeast/Mold",
        "product_spec": "Alert >=3; Action >=5; TNTC (OOS)",
        "sample_number": 792212,
        "status": "A",
        "result": 1,
        "units": "CFU",
        "in_control": "T",
        "in_spec": "T",
        "number_of_samples": 0,
        "number_of_oot": 0,
        "number_of_oos": 0,
        "number_of_tntc": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

JAVA CODE

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
parameters.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_INPUT_STREAM, bais);
print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters);
```

Comment: Posting some sample JSON data would better help understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Added JSON Test Data

Comment: Thank you very much, Narcis - that did it! One last follow-up. I was able to preview the above in the Jasper studio when I defined a default data adapter. Once I removed the adapter, and tried to produce the report from a Java program I am getting an empty report. Relevant JAVA code pasted above.  Thanks

Comment: Java code pasted directly after JSON data - FYI

Comment: Try using `JRLoader` for loading your file: `parameters.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_INPUT_STREAM, JRLoader.getLocationInputStream("path/to/data.json"));`

Answer (score 1):

When you preview the subreport on its own, it works because you are constructing your main dataset from the root of the JSON tree.

But in your main report you send only the `samples_by_result_cfu` subtree to your subreport, so the mapping of JSON keys does not match there(in the subreport) anymore.

There are many ways to fix this, but the most simple ones are:

1. Don't `subDataSource()` by key in the main report, like this:

   ```
   <subreport>
       <reportElement x="-10" y="10" width="570" height="200" uuid="08b3b95b-e7c1-477d-8579-de67c5348404"/>
       <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
       ...
   </subreport>
   ```

Or

2. Prepare your subreport to work directly from the `samples_by_result_cfu` JSON key by:

   2.1. Setting the main dataset's(not the subDataset's) `queryString` to:

   ```
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[report.samples_by_result_cfu]]>
    </queryString>
   ```

   2.2. Set the `dataSourceExpression` for the table's `datasetRun` like so:

   ```
    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="ad76e183-2756-412b-a5c8-1d392d454155">
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("^")]]></dataSourceExpression>
    </datasetRun>
   ```

   The `"^"` expression means "go up one level" so that it lands on the whole array at the `samples_by_result_cfu` key(from step 2.1).